# SwiftUI - navigate after receiving data from network

Tags: swiftui, network-programming

I would like to be able to perform a search, get the data, and navigate to the next screen and display the data.  By doing it in this order I can ensure there is data before navigating.  The problem I am having is the value I am sending to the second screen is nil until the data comes back from the search and I haven't found a good way to handle this.  In the code below I am initializing viewModel.weather with a dummy value to get rid of the optional.

First View Snippet:

```
@StateObject var viewModel = SearchViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: CityWeatherView(weather: viewModel.weather),
                    isActive: $viewModel.navigateToWeatherView,
                    label: {}
                )
```

SearchViewModel:

```
class SearchViewModel: ObservableObject, LocationDelegate {
    
    @Published var searchText = ""
    @Published var weather: OneCallWeatherModel = OneCallWeatherModel.testData
```

Second View

```
struct CityWeatherView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var viewModel: CityWeatherViewModel
    
    init(weather: OneCallWeatherModel) {
        _viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: CityWeatherViewModel(weather: weather))
    }
```

Comment: "I haven't found a good way to handle this"  What is 'this?'  What is the result you expect to happen?  What's so obvious to you is not obvious to everyone else.

Comment: Ideally I would like to be able to get the data and force unwrap the optional since I now know that it definitely isn’t nil, but I can’t figure how to make that work. If I force unwrap it in the NavigationLink it throws an error immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Add `NavigationLink` conditionally only on data present, like

```
class SearchViewModel: ObservableObject, LocationDelegate {
    
    @Published var searchText = ""
    @Published var weather: OneCallWeatherModel?     // << optional
...
}
```

and here is usage

```
ZStack {
   if viewModel.weather != nil { // next will be instantiated when data got fetched
        NavigationLink(
            destination: CityWeatherView(weather: viewModel.weather!),
            isActive: $viewModel.navigateToWeatherView,
            label: {}
        )
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a high level idea with navigationDestination, since NavigationLink with destination should have never existed and they fixed in iOS15 or so. The idea is to have a loading screen and display the real screen only after the data is ready.

```
@State var objects: [Object] = []
@State var isLoaded: Bool = false

List {
    ForEach(objects, id: \.self) { obj in
        NavigationLink(obj.name, value: invoice)
    }
}
.navigationDestination(for: Object.self) { obj in
            if isLoaded {
                Text("Is Loaded")
            } else {
                Text("Loading...")
                    .task {
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(1)) {
                            isLoaded = true
                        }
                    }
            }
}
```